# LWJGL set transparency color?

Tags: opengl, transparency, alpha, lwjgl

I've been playing with LWJGL a little, as a bit of a step up from Pygame. I'm trying to render a sprite and I was wondering if LWJGL has a function similar to Pygame's colorkey that lets you define a color in an image that will be rendered as transparent. Do you have to use an alpha channel in OpenGL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL doesn't have any built in color keying support. You'll need to either manually swap your key for alpha on the CPU, or use a custom shader that replaces it on the fly.